# How do I reference a user's most recently uploaded file in a view, then do something with the file, then return the data?

Tags: django

I'm trying to build a site specific to a product that I make. The product records data from sensors on a CSV file. What I want to do: Users can create an account, upload their CSVs, then, using chart.js, I pass x and y axis data to the template through template tags. 
I have the idea working well with a local CSV test file, but now I need to reference the users specific files in the view, then parse the csv and return the data as context, but I'm stuck on how to reference the specific users csv and how to handle the file in the view.

```
models.py
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

    def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
        return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

    class Document(models.Model):
        docfile = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=user_directory_path)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        def get_upload_path(self,filename):
            return "media/uploads/"+str(self.user.id)+"/"+filename
        def __str__(self):
            return self.description

    class UserProfile(models.Model):

        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        #additional
        portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)

        profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)
        docfiles = models.OneToOneField(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username

views.py

    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, render_to_response, reverse
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.contrib import messages
    from . import parsecsv
    import json
    from .models import Document
    from .forms import UploadFileForm, UserForm, UserProfileForm
    from django.views import View
    from django.views.generic import TemplateView, FormView
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
    from django.urls import reverse
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
    from .forms import UploadFileForm
    from . import parsecsv
    # Create your views here.


    class HomePageView(TemplateView):
        template_name = "EdiApp/index.html"


    def upload(request):
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            docfile = form.save(commit=False)
            docfile.user = request.user
            docfile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('edigraph'))
        else:
            form = UploadFileForm

        return render(request, 'EdiApp/upload.html',{'form':form})

    class EdiGraphView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
        template_name = "EdiApp/edigraph.html"

        def get_queryset(self):
            user = self.request.user
            ds = Document.objects.get(user=user)


            def time(self):
                with open(ds,'r') as csv_file:
                    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
                    next(csv_reader) #takes out header of CSV

                    for line in csv_reader:
                        return [line[0] for line in csv_reader]
            return time()

        #Context referencing a local static file to test the chart.js
        time = str(parsecsv.time()).replace("'","").replace(":","")
        temp = str(parsecsv.temp()).replace("'","")
        emfval = str(parsecsv.emfval()).replace("'","")
        hum = str(parsecsv.hum()).replace("'","")
        pres = str(parsecsv.pres()).replace("'","")
        geo = str(parsecsv.geo()).replace("'","")
        mar = str(parsecsv.mar()).replace("'","")
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(EdiGraphView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context.update({"insert_time": self.time(), "insert_temp": self.temp, "insert_emfval": self.emfval, "insert_hum": self.hum, "insert_pres": self.pres, "insert_geo": self.geo, "insert_mar": self.mar})
            return context



    @login_required
    def user_logout(request):
        logout(request)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))



    def register(request):

        registered = False

        if request.method == "POST":
            user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
            profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

            if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                user = user_form.save()
                user.set_password(user.password)
                user.save()

                profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = user

                if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                    profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

                profile.save()

                registered = True
            else:
                print(user_form.errors)
        else:
            user_form = UserForm()
            profile_form = UserProfileForm()

        return render(request,'EdiApp/registration.html',
                                {'user_form':user_form,
                                  'profile_form':profile_form,
                                  'registered':registered})




    @login_required
    def form_page(request):
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False) #commit=false is so you can manipulate the data before saving it to the database / save after to prevent collision errors
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, "Successfully uploaded")
            # return redirect('EdiApp/index/')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, "EdiApp/form_page.html", context)



    def user_login(request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

            if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request,user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

                else:
                    return HttpResponse("ACCOUTN NOT ACTIVE")

            else:
                print("someone tried to login and failed")
                print("username: {} and password {}".format(username,password))
                return HttpResponse("invalid Login details supplied!")
        else:
            return render(request,'EdiApp/login.html',{})


HTML
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        {% extends "EdiApp/base.html" %}
          {% block body_block %}
          {% load staticfiles %}

        <style type="text/css">
        body {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          background-image: None;
          background-color: rgba(30,30,30,1) !important;
        }
        </style>

        <body class="graphbody">
        <div class="headertext py-4">
          <h3 class="pb-2">Upload Your EdiLog CSV {{ insert_time }} </h3>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'EdiApp:upload' %}">Upload CSV</a>
        </div>

        <hr style="border-color:white;" class="pb-2">

          <div class="wrapper" style="">
          <canvas id="temp"></canvas>
          </div>
          <script type="text/javascript">

          var ctx = document.getElementById("temp");
          var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
              labels: {{ insert_time }},
              datasets: [
                {
                  label: 'Temperature',
                  data: {{ insert_temp }},
                  backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.8)",
                  borderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1.0)",
                  pointBackgroundColor: "black",
                  pointBorderWidth: 0,
                  pointHoverRadius: 8,
                  pointHoverBackgroundColor: "white",
                  pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
                  pointRadius: 1,
                  pointHitRadius: 10,

                }
              ]
            },
            options: {
              responsive: true,
              scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                  gridLines: {
                    color: ['rgba(255,255,255,0.3)']
                  },
                  ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 20
                  },
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                  gridLines: {
                    color: ['rgba(255,255,255,0.3)']
                  },
                }]
              }

                }
          });

          </script>

          <hr style="border-color:white;" class="pb-2">

            <div class="wrapper" style="">
            <canvas id="emf"></canvas>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            var ctx = document.getElementById("emf");
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'line',
              data: {
                labels: {{ insert_time }},
                datasets: [
                  {
                    label: 'EMF',
                    data: {{ insert_emfval }},
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(75, 200, 50, 0.8)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.0)",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "black",
                    pointBorderWidth: 0,
                    pointHoverRadius: 8,
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "white",
                    pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
                    pointRadius: 1,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,

                  }
                ]
              },
              options: {
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                  xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                      color: ['rgba(255,255,255,0.3)']
                    },
                    ticks: {
                      autoSkip: true,
                      maxTicksLimit: 20
                    },
                  }],
                  yAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                      color: ['rgba(255,255,255,0.3)']
                    },
                  }]
                }

                  }
            });

            </script>


            <hr style="border-color:white;" class="pb-2">

              <div class="wrapper" style="">
              <canvas id="geo"></canvas>
              </div>
              <script type="text/javascript">

              var ctx = document.getElementById("geo");
              var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                  labels: {{ insert_time }},
                  datasets: [
                    {
                      label: 'Vibration',
                      data: {{ insert_geo }},
                      backgroundColor: "rgba(138, 43, 226, 0.8)",
                      borderColor: "rgba(75, 0, 130, 1.0)",
                      pointBackgroundColor: "black",
                      pointBorderWidth: 0,
                      pointHoverRadius: 8,
                      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "white",
                      pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
                      pointRadius: 1,
                      pointHitRadius: 10,

                    }
                  ]
                },
                options: {
                  responsive: true,
                  scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                      gridLines: {
                        color: ['rgba(255,255,255,0.3)']
                      },
                      ticks: {
                        autoSkip: true,
                        maxTicksLimit: 20
                      },
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                      gridLines: {
                        color: ['rgba(255,255,255,0.3)']
                      },
                    }]
                  }

                    }
              });

              </script>

              <hr style="border-color:white;" class="pb-2">

                <div class="wrapper" style="">
                <canvas id="hum"></canvas>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                var ctx = document.getElementById("hum");
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                  type: 'line',
                  data: {
                    labels: {{ insert_time }},
                    datasets: [
                      {
                        label: 'Humidity',
                        data: {{ insert_hum }},
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(91,192,222,0.8)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(91,192,222,1)",
                        pointBackgroundColor: "black",
                        pointBorderWidth: 0,
                        pointHoverRadius: 8,
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "white",
                        pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
                        pointRadius: 1,
                        pointHitRadius: 10,

                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                      xAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                          color: ['rgba(255,255,255,0.3)']
                        },
                        ticks: {
                          autoSkip: true,
                          maxTicksLimit: 20
                        },
                      }],
                      yAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                          color: ['rgba(255,255,255,0.3)']
                        },
                      }]
                    }

                      }
                });

                </script>


                      <hr style="border-color:white;" class="pb-2">

                        <div class="wrapper" style="">
                        <canvas id="pres"></canvas>
                        </div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">

                        var ctx = document.getElementById("pres");
                        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                          type: 'line',
                          data: {
                            labels: {{ insert_time }},
                            datasets: [
                              {
                                label: 'Pressure',
                                data: {{ insert_pres }},
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                                borderColor: "rgba(90,90,90,1)",
                                pointBackgroundColor: "black",
                                pointBorderWidth: 0,
                                pointHoverRadius: 8,
                                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "white",
                                pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
                                pointRadius: 1,
                                pointHitRadius: 10,

                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          options: {
                            responsive: true,
                            scales: {
                              xAxes: [{
                                gridLines: {
                                  color: ['rgba(255,255,255,0.3)']
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                  autoSkip: true,
                                  maxTicksLimit: 20
                                },
                              }],
                              yAxes: [{
                                gridLines: {
                                  color: ['rgba(255,255,255,0.3)']
                                },
                              }]
                            }

                              }
                        });

                        </script>


        </body>
          {% endblock %}


parsecsv.py the file I use to parse the CSV and get the test context

    import csv
    import datetime



    def time():
        with open('EDILOG01.CSV','r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            next(csv_reader) #takes out header of CSV

            for line in csv_reader:
                return [line[0] for line in csv_reader]


    def emfval():
        with open('EDILOG01.CSV','r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            next(csv_reader, None) #takes out header of CSV

            for line in csv_reader:
                return [line[1] for line in csv_reader]


    def temp():
        with open('EDILOG01.CSV','r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            next(csv_reader, None) #takes out header of CSV

            for line in csv_reader:
                return [line[2] for line in csv_reader]

    def hum():
        with open('EDILOG01.CSV','r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            next(csv_reader, None) #takes out header of CSV

            for line in csv_reader:
                return [line[3] for line in csv_reader]

    def pres():
        with open('EDILOG01.CSV','r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            next(csv_reader, None) #takes out header of CSV

            for line in csv_reader:
                return [line[4] for line in csv_reader]

    def geo():
        with open('EDILOG01.CSV','r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            next(csv_reader, None) #takes out header of CSV

            for line in csv_reader:
                return [line[5] for line in csv_reader]

    def mar():
        with open('EDILOG01.CSV','r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            next(csv_reader, None) #takes out header of CSV

            for line in csv_reader:
                return [line[6] for line in csv_reader]
```

Eventually, I would like the user to be able to select from a list of Uploaded CSVs, then the one selected would be put into the context tags to be presented, but I'm struggling with just referencing the most recent file the user uploaded and returning the context.

I'm fairly new to python and Django, and as I read through the documentation, I feel like the answer is right in front of me, though I just don't know exactly what to do with it. Any input would be a tremendous help, thank you all!

Comment: This seems like the wrong approach. Surely it would be better to parse the file on upload and store the data in a model?

Comment: I was thinking about that.. But, if I have multiple files I don't know how to keep the data separate, if that makes sense..

Comment: But you only care about the latest one, apparently. So whenever a new file is uploaded you delete all data for that user and replace it with the new stuff.

Comment: To get the project started, yes, I am only trying to retrieve the latest upload. I was hoping to eventually allow the user to upload multiple CSV files and be able to see the graphs from whichever file they choose.